How can a Bluetooth receiver detect signals from a specific device?
If 2 devices send Bluetooth signals on the same channel (Hence they have the same frequency for '0' and '1'), how does the receiver detect the 'right' '0' and '1'?

You can't transmit simultaneously on a wireless channel, so Bluetooth detects if there is noise on the channel before transmitting:

One of the major challenges in radio communications concerns
collisions, which are particularly problematic in busy radio
environments. Earlier we explored collisions and explained that a
collision occurs when two or more devices transmit data on the same
radio channel in overlapping time periods, and that different radio
technologies such as Bluetooth® technology and Wi-Fi can interfere
with each other if their use of the radio spectrum overlaps.
Bluetooth technology mitigates the risk of collisions through its use
of spread spectrum techniques. When two devices are connected, this
involves a specific technique known as adaptive frequency hopping.
At each connection event, a pair of connected devices have the
opportunity to use their radios to exchange packets at precisely timed
intervals. But in addition to this, at the start of each connection
event, frequency hopping occurs, with a radio channel being
deterministically selected from the set of available channels using a
channel selection algorithm. Each device in the connection will then
switch to the selected channel and over time and a series of
connection events, communication will take place using a frequently
changing series of different channels, distributed across the 2.4 GHz
band, thereby significantly reducing the probability of collisions
occurring.
https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/how-bluetooth-technology-uses-adaptive-frequency-hopping-to-overcome-packet-interference/

If there were devices that transmitted at the same time it could cause an error, at which the packet would need to be resent or dropped.


If there are 79 channels on the Bluetooth spectrum, does it mean that in the current environment there could be only 79 Bluetooth communications?                                                            2. How does a Bluetooth device detect '0' and '1' as error?


Yes there can only be as many devices transmitting as there are channels, bluetooth also uses TDM to break the channels up into multiple time divisions to increase the number of devices that could potentially talk. If you have more than that it will depend on how often they transmit.

Great!    If there were devices that transmitted at the same time it could cause an error - >> how error is detected? [How receiver can detect that there are signals from multiple masters]

RF symbols are not coded directly to 1 and 0. Even if they were, a packet has a CRC field. If the received data's CRC doesn't match, the packet is dropped.

With traditional broadcast radio such as AM and FM, the FCC or similar organization allocates specific frequencies to stations in a geographic area so that they don't overlap. The result is that normally you turn to a frequency and you will only get one station - no ambiguity.
With air traffic control, specific frequencies are allocated for different purposes, with the frequency used by an airplane changing several times over the course of a trip. There are some general frequencies as well (e.g., 121.5 Mhz). But in any case sometimes two people do talk at the same time and have to manually adapt to the situation. Identification is provided by identifying yourself verbally in each message.
But Bluetooth is a digital radio using packets. Each packet includes a preamble (to get things ready), an access address (the key here), data (what you are actually trying to send) and a CRC (to make sure things were received properly).
See this page about Bluetooth Packet Structure for a lot more details. But as I understand it, the access address is a pseudo-random value that meets particular parameters and is used for the duration of the communications session (i.e., after initial negotiation/authentication) to identify a device. It is this value which lets each receiver determine whether a packet is for their use (for your cell phone rather than someone else's cell phone or computer or whatever) and what to do with it.
